# Creating custom endpoint for WordPress REST API not registering

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-rest-api

I've followed several examples and can't seem to register a custom endpoint. I'm creating a custom plugin and want to register a custom endpoint. Here is my code:

```
add_action( 'init', 'setup_init' );


function setup_init() {

   add_action( 'rest_api_init', 'wpc_register_wp_api_endpoints' );

   function wpc_register_wp_api_endpoints() {

    register_rest_route( 'setup', '/client/menu', array(
        'methods' => 'GET',
        'callback' => 'menu_setup',
    ));
}

   function menu_setup($request_data){
       return 'hello world';
   }
}
```

I visit mysite.com/setup/client/menu and I get a page not found error. I then check mysite.com/wp-json/wp/v2/ and I do not see my route/end point is registered. My plugin is enabled. Am I doing something  wrong?

Answer (score 0):

There is one small mistake of registering the endpoints. Replace the line:

```
register_rest_route( 'setup', '/client/menu'
```

with:

```
register_rest_route( 'setup/client', '/menu'
```

*Below is full snippet of your code:*

```
add_action( 'init', 'setup_init' );


function setup_init() {

   add_action( 'rest_api_init', 'wpc_register_wp_api_endpoints' );

   function wpc_register_wp_api_endpoints() {

    register_rest_route( 'setup/client', '/menu', array(
        'methods' => 'GET',
        'callback' => 'menu_setup',
    ));
}

   function menu_setup($request_data){
       return 'hello world';
   }
}
```

Let me know if any query and do accept the answer if it works :)

Comment: Thanks for the formatting @Jee ;) Accept the answers if its true. It will help to others :)